# What is the name given to tables that hold static information

Tags: c#, java, javascript, sql, oracle

I am working on a large project that contains many reference / look up type tables. This is maybe not the correct place to ask this question but I would like to find out the name that people give in English to these kind of tables:

The tables contain data such as status_code, status_type. They are preloaded and the data in them will probably never change.

Please excuse my not knowing this but ENglish is not my first language and I need to do a presentatation to talk about these kind of tables.

Comment: the best word i can think of is "report"

Comment: Could you provide an example? Something like `var Status = { Failure: 0, Success: 1 }`, which would be called an enum (mostly because of how they're used in other languages, although JavaScript technically does not have enums as you can get away with things like `Status.Failure = 2`).

Comment: Yes just like your wrote where the status table can have "Failure", "Success", "Ready" and then there are more tables that cover things like the materials used in buildings. All these tables are used to populate drop down lists.

Comment: People give different names - LookUpData, ReferenceData, StaticData, etc depending upon the properties of data.

Comment: Yeah, if it's merely assigning integers to keys, in most languages those are enums. But really, these are all objects in JS, and the answers others gave are good, especially if you have things like `var Status = { Failure: { message: "Oh no!", value: 0 }, Success: /* ... */ }`. There's no fixed name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

People give different names - LookUpData, ReferenceData, StaticData, etc depending upon the properties of data. Is this answer your questions? If not, probably you need to be more elaborative.

Answer (score 1):

The most often used english name I've encountered is 'static data'. This indicates that the data does not change very often.

Aside: one interesting aspect of static data is that it is a good candidate for caching.

Answer (score 0):

Where the tables contain data that's interesting to the application, but do reflect not the outside world - status codes, for instance - I tend to call them enumeration tables.

Where the table contains values that change rarely, but do reflect the outside world - cities, currencies, etc. - I tend to call them lookup tables.

Where tables contain "friendly" values - e.g translating ISO country/locale codes - I tend to call them reference tables.

Answer (score 0):

We tend to use the term "Reference Data". But there isn't a standard term, it varies a lot in my experience.  I haven't heard "Static Data" before, but I like it.